# Python: Nested For Loops To Find Difference In Elements In List --> One Loop Test & Appending to Output List

Tags: python, for-loop, append

I'm thoroughly confused!

I have a list below:

```
prices = [13, 11, 10, 8, 5]
```

I want to write code that reverses the list to create `[5, 8, 10, 11, 13]` and subtracts each term from 5 and append that to a new list.

So my desired output would be: [`-3, -5, -6, -8]`

I wrote the code below using break to test just one loop:

```
def max_profit(prices):
    ###
    ### YOUR CODE HERE
    prices_reversed = list(reversed(prices))
    print (f'prices_reversed is: {prices_reversed}')
    
    profit_amt_list = []

    for i in range(len(prices_reversed)):
        print (f'i is: {i}')
        current_value = prices_reversed[i]
        
        for j in range(i,len(prices_reversed)):
            print (j)
            
            if j+1 < len(prices_reversed):
                print ('true')
                next_value = prices_reversed[j+1]
        
            # print (current_value, next_value)
            profit_amt_list.append(current_value - next_value)
            
        break
        
    print (profit_amt_list)

    ###

max_profit(prices)
```

my code prints:

```
prices_reversed is: [5, 8, 10, 11, 13]
i is: 0
0
true
1
true
2
true
3
true
4
**[-3, -5, -6, -8, -8]**
```

For the life of me I don't understand why I have two -8 values when the list should only contain one.  Please help me understand!

Comment: why don't you expect the output to be `[0, -3, -5, -6, -8]` ?  Any reason why the first item of the reversed list should be skipped ?  Other wise `[x-5 for x in reversed(prices)]` would suffice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have confused your looping.

First of all, your outer loop is absolutely useless.  You never use the value of `i`, and you *always* break after the first iteration.  Get rid of that loop.

The problem with your `j` loop is that although you're trying to find a simple difference, you complicate the matter too much to see the problem.  On the final iteration, instead of stopping (you have 5 numbers, so will have only 4 differences), you simply don't bother to update `next_value`, and you loop once more.  Since none of the critical values have changed, you perform 5-13 a second time and add it to the `profit_amt_list`.

Since `current_value` is always `5`, the first element of the list, just do the direct computation:

```
profit_amt_list = []
price = prices_reversed[0]
for value in prices_reversed[1:]:
    profit_amt_list.append(price - value)

    print (profit_amt_list)
```

Final output:

```
[-3, -5, -6, -8]
```

Comment: thank you!  the break is just temporary for debugging purposes ... it needs to be removed so the i can loop once the debugging problem is figured out

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([13, 11, 10, 8, 5])
arr = np.flip(arr)
arr = 5 - arr

print(arr[arr != 0])
```

output

```
[-3, -5, -6, -8]
```

or like this if you want it to print top to bottom.

```
for x in arr[arr != 0]:
    print(x)
```

output

```
-3
-5
-6
-8
```

Comment: @PineNuts0 this is ideal if you're working with a huge array of prices.